# assembly - call printf with 64 bit memory content

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to add the number 0xFFFFFFFF with himself and then print the result to screen.
For this, I'm using the memory location `result` to hold the results (that may be up to 64bit).
In order to call `printf`, I need to push it to stack but this: `push qword [result]` not compiled. there is any way to send the 64 bit number to `printf`?

```
section .data
fmt1: dq "%x", 10, 0
result: dd 0,0

section .text
    extern printf  

assFunc:

mov edx,0
mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF
add eax, 0xFFFFFFFF
adc edx,0


mov [result],edx
mov [result+4],eax

push [result]
push fmt1
call printf
add esp,8
```

Comment: You will need to do it in two halves. `push dword [result+4]; push dword [result]`. Note that `%x` does not take a 64 bit number. Also your `fmt1` should be `db` not `dq` (although it is probably harmless).

Comment: You should store the low half of the value in `[result]` and the high half in `[result+4]` to match the way all multibyte values are stored on x86. Note that the comment by @Jester was written with the assumption that it is stored this way.

Comment: @prl good catch!

Comment: thank u both! I changed to `push dword [result+4]; push dword [result]` but still not understand how to print the decimal value correctly. this `fmt1: db "%d%d", 10, 0` not working

Comment: Use `%lld` (once).

Comment: @Jester thanks. this is working but one of the assignment requirement is to user only %d ("prints result in decimal base, using printf with '%d' format"). can I do it with my approach?

Comment: If you can only use `%d` but you are allowed multiple calls it might actually be simplest to do a conversion to decimal yourself and print the digits one by one.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

The `fmt` string is defined with `dq` which defines groups of QWORDs (64-bit items).  This has the effect of padding (with zero bytes) every string to multiple of 8 bytes.
In this case, you would lose the new line char.
Use `db` instead.

It's also better to follow the little endian convention and store the high part of a number in the higher addresses.
`edx` is the high part of the result, store it in `[result + 4]` and store `eax` (the lower part) in `[result]`.
This makes it easy for other programmers to reason about your code. [By the same length, you can also use `xor edx, edx` to set `edx` to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).

Finally, the printing part.
First of all, the correct format string is `%llx` since the model used by the mainstream compilers in 32-bit mode is LL64 (i.e. `long` is still 32 bits, while `long long` is 64 bits).

The ABI says you have to pass `long long` arguments on the stack and that their alignment is 4 bytes (which means, you *don't* have to add any padding).
Furthermore, [the ABI mandates](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf) that the stack to be aligned on 16 bytes boundary just before the `call` instruction but, by sheer luck, using three pushes is what was needed to keep it aligned anyway.
Since x86 are little endian machines, this can be accomplished with:

```
push DWORD [result+4]
push DWORD [result]
push fmt1
call printf
add esp, 10h
```

The whole code:

```
SECTION .data

  fmt1:   db "%llx", 10, 0
  result: dd 0, 0


SECTION .text

    EXTERN printf  

assFunc:

  mov edx,0
  mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF
  add eax, 0xFFFFFFFF
  adc edx,0

  mov [result],eax
  mov [result+4],edx

  push DWORD [result+4]
  push DWORD [result]
  push fmt1
  call printf
  add esp, 0ch 

  ret
```

Note that you don't actually need to store the result in the `result` variable, you can

```
push edx
push eax
```

directly, instead of

```
push DWORD [result+4]
push DWORD [result]
```

Comment: thank you very much! can  you explain more about " In this case, you would lose the new line char."? why?

Comment: @govegan Because by using `dq` the string "%x" is padded with 6 zero bytes. And `printf` stops at the first zero byte it founds.